# Changing only text font to Times New Roman but keep maths symbols in default font

Tags: fonts

In my document, I have math symbols/equations, as well as plain text, the text has to be in Times New Roman font, so I use `\usepackage{pslatex}`. However, this also changes the font of the maths symbols as well as anything encapsulated by `$$`. Is there a way to have just my text in Times New Roman font but the math symbols all in default LaTeX font? For example:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Following \cite{yu}, we employ maximum constant relative risk aversion utility and minimum value at risk for optimisation. The resulting two optimization models are:
\begin{gather*}
\max\left[\left(w_1\exp\left(r\Delta t\right)\right)^{1-\gamma_1}/(1-\gamma_1) + \sum_{i=2}^6 \exp\left(w_i\left(\alpha_i - 0.5 \sigma_i^2 \right)\Delta t \right)^{1-\gamma_i}/(1-\gamma_i) \right] \\
\min\left[\sum_{i=2}^6 w_i \exp\left(\left(\alpha_i - 0.5\sigma_i^2 \right)\Delta t / \sigma_i \sqrt{\Delta t} + \Phi^{-1}\left(\beta_i \right) \right) \right]
\end{gather*}
where $\gamma_i$ is the relative risk aversion coefficient for asset $i$, $w_i$ is the weighting of asset $i$, $\Delta t$ is the length of the investment period, $\beta_i$ is the confidence level of the value at risk of asset $i$, and $\Phi^{-1}$ is the standard normal inverse cumulative distribution function.

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

However, I would like the maths equations/symbols to appear with the following font: (Note: ignore the text font here)
[image]

This is only one excerpt from my document, I have many maths symbols in `align`, `gather`, `$$` environments, how can I universally change all maths symbols to default LaTeX font?

Comment: Use only \renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm} instead of you package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer An answer?

Comment: `\usepackage{newtxtext}`

Comment: I agree that the result of `\usepackage{mathptmx}` is not typographically good. But mixing Computer Modern math italic with Times New Roman is certainly worse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use only `\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}` instead of your package.

You can also use a font package like newtxtext (as suggested by Manual), or tgtermes, or even times (which would also change the sans serif and the tt). All of them affect only the text font.